# DEC to HEX conversion with filling empty with 0 in bash

Tags: bash, hex

I have to convert decimal number to hexadecimal, but with filling eventual voids with zeroes:

Example:

I've tried this:

```
printf "%X\n" 190
```

Output is:

```
BE
```

i need it to look like this:

```
00BE
```

In short, output should have 4 hex symbols, if less, it should be filled with zeroes at the beginning

How to do that in bash?

Comment: Perhaps you used `%X` and not `%x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use format specifiers:

```
$ printf "%04X\n" 190
00BE
```

```
$ printf "%04X\n" 1
0001
$ printf "%04X\n" 42
002A
```